# PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(myIPaddshere/uploads/code_snippet.docx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files to my website on line.I have following code that working fine for me on localhost but when i put the same on website it's giving me PHP Warning:

> move_uploaded_file(myIPhere/uploads/code_snippet.docx): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hindustantalent.com\httpdocs\reg.php\line no 61  PHP
>   Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\windows\Temp\phpA6A7.tmp' to
>   'MyIPhere/uploads/code_snippet.docx' in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hindustantalent.com\httpdocs\reg.php\line no 61

I already have created a folder their namely uploads still it is giving this warning and i am unable to understand that.Can anybody help me plz

Comment: This is `69.167.138.104/uploads/code_snippet.docx` not absolute path. Use absolute path.

Comment: Please remove IP from question. Your Plesk server is open

Comment: @Sushant  though it have no media :D

Comment: I got this to get absolute path for my file  $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";                                                               what content/parameters  I should suppose to put into it

Comment: Anybody plz help.. I  really dont know how to  do this

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507